# Issue with forward slash in java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for the following data:

All digits, all letters, or combination of  digits and letters including special characters allowed:

```
@ . – ‘ ? , ( ) : ; ! * $  _  =  + ^  &  #
```

and French Unicode Accent Characters.

Please help. I am using the following regular expression, which works fine for other characters but it somehow allows forward slash`(/)`.

```
VALIDATOR_STRING = "^[A-Za-z0-9éÉèÈçÇâÂêÊôÔ@.'#,-?:;!*$_=+^&()]+$";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the dash `-` in a character class (like in `A-Z`), it denotes a range (in this example every capital letter between `A` and `Z`).

So you allow the range between `,-?` which contains the forward slash. If you look at http://www.asciitable.com you'll see that this range contains every of the following characters: `, . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?`

To avoid this behaviour, place the dash as the first or last character in the character class:

```
VALIDATOR_STRING = "^[-A-Za-z0-9éÉèÈçÇâÂêÊôÔ@.'#,?:;!*$_=+^&()]+$";
```

Comment: And/Or you can escape it with a backslash (like any other special character). `"[A\\-Z]"` will match `A - Z`

Comment: Thanks jlordo and Marc!